# Why does using my code in replit instead of vsc give me different results when the code is the same?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, discord-buttons

I am trying to implement the discord.js button feature into my bot, not as a command but just to get the feel of it. I followed a tutorial and wrote a command for it, which i put in a file in my commands folder. The code for the command is  below-
I ran the code in replit, and saw no errors. After this, i tried  the command in discord but there was no response, and no error in the console.

```js
const discord = require ("discord.js");
const { MessageButton } = require ("discord-buttons");

module.exports = {
 name: 'smart',
 aliases:[],
 run: async (Client,message,args,prefix) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return

    const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Are you smart?")
      .setColour("BLUE")

    const ye = new MessageButton()
      .setStyle("green")
      .setLabel("yes")
      .setID("smart")

    const nu = new MessageButton()
      .setStyle("red")
      .setLabel("no")
      .setID("idiot")

    message.channel.send("Hello",{
      buttons: [yes,no],
      embed: embed
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean `buttons: [ye,nu],` instead of `buttons: [yes,no],` ?

Comment: @NullDev yeah my bad, i noticed that and changed it, however this made no difference to the problem i am facing. I am left without a message/error

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for this yet?

Comment: Try to check the node.js version installed on your pc and on replit, do the same for the packges.

Comment: @AndreaGennaioli My bot requires a lot of packages, which i had to install by using npm install for each and every one of them. I am using node version 14.17.2 currently

Comment: Just wanted you to know, i have switched to hosting the bot on my computer, which i keep on constantly, i customised a power mode in windows to turn the screen off but keep the terminal open.

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for this? i need help